# Can Visual Studio C++ header/lib files be used to build on a machine without Visual Studio installed?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, clang, cross-compiling

I am attempting to cross-compile a Windows application on Linux using Clang, and based on their [CMake file](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/llvm/cmake/platforms/WinMsvc.cmake), it looks like I need to copy the header and lib files from a Visual Studio installation. I have Visual Studio 2015, but it looks like the [list of redistributable files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/productinfo/2015-redistribution-vs#bldsrv) doesn't include those. They are in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include" for me, and that's not on the list. So, am I allowed to use those header/lib files on a machine that doesn't have a Visual Studio license, or is there some other way to get these files?

Comment: Isn't going to work, you can't copy system header files and libraries across took-chains like that.  Please include a short sample of the what you think is missing (that you would need to copy), there might be an alternative approach.

Comment: @RichardCritten Have you looked at the linked CMake file? It specifically says to get the headers/libraries from MSVC.

Comment: I have now and 2 things jump out: _"...intalled by MSVC 2017..."_ and _"...or versions of MSVC < 2017, or where you have a hermetic toolchain in a custom format, you must use symlinks or restructure it to look like the above...."_  And legal question should be asked of your lawyer as any free opinion is worth what you paid for it.